Is this carbon fork damaged?
How can I know if this carbon fork is damaged ?
The seller of the bike tells me that he didn't fall, but I can't know for sure.
How can these scratch happen otherwise ?
Also there are some on the seat stay.



One previous answer has a number of reference photos that may help.

A clarification that may be useful to further readers: the Allez has an aluminium frame and a carbon fork. Even if the question is about the fork, it useful to know that difference to avoid a direct comparison.

Looking just at the first photo - the fork looks to be almost totally paint scratches, because we can see the white undercoat.   These are cosmetic and likely the result of careless parking/storage or a bike stand.
There is one roundish ding just above the A of ALLEZ which has a dark center.  Run your fingernail over it, or look really closely under bright light.  If you can see loose fibres then the carbon fibres have been broken.
If there are no loose fibres, protect the area with some clear or colour-matched nail varnish.
Use your best judgement on the seller - consider they want to sell their bike to anyone.
Also look at the other side of the fork blade, and both sides of the other leg of the fork.  Perhaps drop out the front wheel for better visibility.
No-one can tell you 100% if its safe to ride - instead you have to balance your risk acceptance against the price.  For the most risk reduction, spend the money and buy new but even then there's a small risk the bike won't be perfect.

Renaud's makes a good point that the frame is Aluminium and the fork is Carbon Fibre.  As such the rear triangle damage, while visually worse is less concerning overall.
Keep an eye on it when you do your regular maintenance, and if there are changes over time then re-evaluate.

You cannot tell the internal structure by the outer layer. For example, take a rubber mallet on your frame. Give it a good whack, the outer layer is intact but the internal layers have delaminated. The only good advice is to never buy a carbon component that has any visible damage. And even then there is a risk of invisible internal damage. This is the economical and environmental price of having the lightest and greatest components on earth.

@Torben did you mean to post that as an answer rather than a comment ?

I do have Allez for couple of years and I fell several times. No high-speed accidents, but unpleasant meetups with a ditch. Although it is a roadbike I use it more like a gravel even with panniers.
The scratches on the front carbon-fibre fork may originate from careless storing or more likely from careless transport in the train/car. Hard and sharp object touching it and scratching every bounce. As Criggie already advised, check for loose carbon fibres and little cracks that might show structural compromise of the fork. Otherwise it looks like aesthetical problem.
The hits on the rear aluminium fork are not just scratches, especially the upper one. It looks like a hard hit from hard and sharp object. It may be something heavy fell on the bike or the bike hit something quite fast and hard. The silverish "stain" on the lower fork looks like exposed base aluminium alloy.
All in all it suggests the bike had a tough time before. So again Criggie's suggestion: Inspect the bike thoroughly.
No-one can say any bike is 100% safe, there are always risks of hidden or not-spotted failure. With a new bike from reputable brand/builder the odds are just lower than for no-name abused bike.
If you are really in buying this bike you can try checking other Allez bikes and check for possible differences (bent fork, bent frame). All those scratches and dents suggest the bike wasn't treated carefully so you can bargain on that.
If you decide to buy, repair all the dents with the nail varnish and observe it. Start with easy rides (no on-the-edge cornerings, high-speed descends) and increase the loads with time. And watch the repairs for new cracks etc.
